# Shimura varieties/Double coset for non-neat level

Tags: algebraic-geometry

First, let $X$ be a finite disjoint union of Hermitian symmetric domains (HSD), $G$ a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $U\subset G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})$ an open compact subgroup of the finite adelic points of $G$. In the theory of Shimura varities we encounter the double coset space $X_U = G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash X\times G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})/U$. We let $X$ and $G$ be as above, not necessarily a Shimura datum for now (and $U$ is also not supposed to be neat/sufficiently small). The double coset $X_U$ is then a finite disjoint union of sets of the form $\Gamma_i \backslash X^+$ where $X^+$ is a connected component of $X$ and $\Gamma_i \subset G(\mathbb{Q})$ are some well-defined (discrete) arithmetic subgroups of $G(\mathbb{Q})$ (even congruence subgroups). I will now just write down my thoughts here and would be very grateful if someone could tell me in which points of thought or statements I am wrong (or maybe everything is ok like this?). According to Bailey-Borel, the $\Gamma_i\backslash X^+$ are normal quasi-projective varieties over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, since they can be embedded into the projective minimal/Satake-Bailey-Borel compactification, which is a normal projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. For this embedding we do not need the $\Gamma_i$ to be torsion-free or U to be sufficiently small. This should always work in this general context (note that we did not suppose $(G,X)$ to be a Shimura datum or $U$ to be small enough!) - but do we need something like "$G(\mathbb{R})^+$ acting transitively on $X^+$" or something? If the $\Gamma_i$ are torsion-free, for example neat or if $U$ is small enough, then $X_U$ is a finite disjoint union of smooth quasi-projective varieties of the form $\Gamma_i \backslash X^+$ and thus smooth quasi-projective itself. The difference between torsion-free and non-torsion-free $\Gamma_i$, however, is that the canonical maps $\text{Sh}_K(G,X) \to \text{Sh}_{K'}(G,X)$ for $K \subset K'$ are only (algebraically) regular (meaning algebraic morphisms of the underlying normal complex varieties) with certainty (in which case they are finite etale) only if $K$ and $K'$ (or only $K'$ since $K$ then automatically also is) are small enough (e.g. neat), because otherwise these mappings are just analytic covering maps between the (normal) complex-analytic spaces $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ and $\text{Sh}_{K'}(G,X)$ (which are not complex manifolds if $K$ and $K'$ are not small enough, but only complex-analytic spaces/orbifolds due to singularities). Thus, if $K$ and $K'$ are not sufficiently small, then we cannot algebraically relate the Shimura varieties of different levels and the tower of Shimura varieties cannot be algebraically formed since this requires finite etale morphisms as transition maps. Thus, in the context of the tower of Shimura varieties, it is always assumed that $K$ is sufficiently small so that the covering maps are regular morphisms between the underlying complex varieties, although the double coset $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ is a normal quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ even for non-sufficiently small (open compact) $K \subset G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})$. But for the study of the level $K$ Shimura varieties $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ should not assumed to be sufficiently small, as one works also with the modular curves $\Gamma \backslash \mathfrak{H}$ (where $\mathfrak{H}$ is the upper half plane in the complex plane) with non-torsionfree $\Gamma$, for example $\Gamma = \Gamma_0(N)$ or $\Gamma = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and also for other non sufficiently small $\Gamma$ or $K$ one gets interpretations of $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ or $\Gamma \backslash \mathfrak{H}$ as moduli spaces of abelian varieties or elliptic curves with certain structures such as polarization, level structure (+...). Thus, in the context of interpretation as moduli spaces, $K$ need not to be sufficiently small. Furthermore: the components $\Gamma_i \backslash X^+$ of $X_U$ from the beginning are for general $\Gamma_i$ resp. (open compact) $U \subset G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})$ quasi-projective varieties over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, but have models over a number field $E$ only in the context of a Shimura datum $(G,X)$ and sufficiently small $K$ for $\text{Sh}_K(G,X) = X_K$ (since this fact argues with the conjugacy class of the Hodge cocharacter $\mu$), and here it is essential that $K$ be sufficiently small or would it work even if $K$ were arbitrary (open compact)? In particular, the whole tower $\{\text{Sh}_K(G,X)\}_K = \{X_K\}_K$, where $K$ ranges over all compact open small enough (or not necessarily small enough) $K\subset G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})$, has models over $E$ all together (this goes wrong for connected Shimura data). But the single double cosets $X_U$ from the beginning in general (with $(G,X)$ not assumed to be a Shimura datum) do not have a model over a number field, even if they are varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ for general (open compact) $U \subset G(\mathbb{A}_\text{fin})$, because here we explicitly need a Shimura datum $(G,X)$ for this to work with the model over a number field $E$. The connected level $K$ Shimura variety $\text{Sh}°_K(G,X^+)$ for a connected Shimura datum $(G,X^+)$ also have models over a number field $F$ (with $K$ sufficiently small or not?), but unlike a Shimura datum, the whole tower has no such model over a number field $F$ (this is where the components of the Shimura varieties come in, giving us a model of the whole tower over $F$).

It would be really very important to me if someone could go into every single point or read through everything carefully and tell me at which point what exactly is wrong/inaccurate/.... This is of enormous importance to me and I would be very grateful to get help! I need to understand these things, otherwise I feel very uncomfortable working further with Shimura varieties.

Comment: "Thus, in the context of interpretation as moduli spaces, K need not to be sufficiently small". This is something you have to be quite careful with, if $K$ is not sufficiently small then fine moduli spaces do not exist and one works with coarse moduli spaces instead. For example this is why people will often work with modular curves of level $\Gamma_1(N)$ with $N \ge $ or $\Gamma(N)$ with $N \ge 3$.