# Shimura Varieties actual varieties for any level?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Since I have not been answered on my other thread [Shimura varieties/Double coset for non-neat level](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043086/shimura-varieties-double-coset-for-non-neat-level) so far and I can't work with this uncertainty, I'll just put down the most important questions here. I would still be grateful if someone would take time for the other thread. Let $(G,X)$ be a Shimura datum. Are the level $K$ varieties $\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ also (quasi-projective) varieties if $K$ is not sufficiently small (in which case they are normal)? Do the $X_K=\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ also have models over a number field if $K$ is not sufficiently small? Does the tower of Shimura varieties $\{X_K\}$ have a model over $E$ even if $K$ runs through all open compact $K$? Now let $D$ be a general Hermitian symmetric domain and $\Gamma \subset \text{Is}^+(D,g)$ a discrete subgroup of the holomorphic isometry group of $D$. Bailey-Borel says $\Gamma\backslash D$ is a normal quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ for any $\Gamma$ (not necessarily torsionfree). Does it have a model over a number field?

Answer (score 2):

First as you said Bailey-Borel theorem says that $D/\Gamma$ is analyticification of a quasi-projective smooth variety for any torison free $\Gamma$ and a quasi-projective normal variety for any $\Gamma$.

you can understand all $Sh(G,X)_K$ as varieties, and they all have canonical models over reflex field.(although sometimes it is better to look at the $Sh(G,X)_K$ for big $K$ as a stack because the variety is only a coarse solution to moduli problem you want to consider).

all the connected components have a model over some number field so $D/\Gamma$ always have a model over some number field for any $\Gamma$ that comes from a congurance subgroup of some $G$ such that $G^{ad}=Hol(D)$.maybe for any $\Gamma$ you can find a model over a number field but this model is not in any way canonical and after all the interesting point about canonical models is that you have a model over a fixed number field otherwise you only want a model over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

*just to clarify what I mean by look at big level shimura variety as a stack: you can write $Sh(G,X)_K=Sh(G,X)_{K'}/\frac{K}{K'}$ for a neat group $K'$, this quotient is represented by a normal quasi-projective variety in the category of schemes(because $\frac{K}{K'}$ is a finite group) but sometimes it is better to look at the quotient stack which could be equal to that normal variety or not.

Comment: Dear Ali thank you very much for your answer! Just to clarify: 1. $(G,X)$ be a Shimura datum. The $X_K=\text{Sh}_K(G,X)$ for $K$ open compact are always normal quasi-projective varieties and defined over some reflex field (number field). But for big $K$ they generally only give coarse moduli solutions instead of fine ones. And thus it is better to look at the $X_K$ as stacks for big $K$ instead of variety. Did I understand it correct up to here? 
And 2.

Comment: And 2. The $D/\Gamma$ as in my opening question above ($D$ Hermitian symmetric domain, $\Gamma \subset \text{Hol}^+(D)$) are normal quasi-projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ and have a model over some number field for any $\Gamma$. But as $\Gamma$ varies, the number field changes and in the whole tower $\{D/\Gamma\}_\Gamma$ only gets a model over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ instead of over a fixed number field. I was clear about this because the tower attached to a connected Shimura datum is not defined over a fixed number field in contrast to a general Shimura datum. But does the

Comment: If $(G,X)$ is a (general) Shimura datum, then the tower $\{X_U\}_U$ of Shimura varieties is defined over a fixed number field where $U$ runs through all sufficiently small (open compact) $U$. And I know that the single $X_U$ have a canonical model over some number field for any $U$ (not only small enough $U$) if I understood you correctly. But is the tower $\{X_U\}_U$ also defined over a fixed number field when $U$ runs through all (!) compact open $U$ and not just the small enough ones? That's my last question.

Comment: @yes your first comment is right.for your third comment yes the whole tower is defined over a fixed number field(which called the reflex field). for your second comment I'm not sure about general $\Gamma$, but for any congurance subgroup it is defined over some number field but the number field is depend on $\Gamma$

Comment: Dear Ali, I see. Thank you very much, your answers were really very helpful!

Comment: I have one very last question. If $K \subset K'$ are neat, then the map $p: \text{Sh}_K (G,X) \to \text{Sh}_{K'}(G,X)$ is a finite etale morphism. What can we say about the degree of the map $p$: Is it equal the index $[K':K$]? And is this map $p$ a Galois cover if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $K'$, with deck transformation group/Galois group of $p$ egal $K'/K$?

Comment: @VitalyVoedevsky this realy has not anything to do with shimura varieties, basically you are asking if you have a variety $X$ and a good action of a finite etale group on it(the finite group$K'/K$ in your case, the action is good because the subgroups are neat) then what properties the qutient map $X\to Y$ has?the answer is it has all the good properties you think. you can check any book that discuss the qutient of action of a finite group on a scheme to see the exact statement

Comment: @VitalyVoedevsky also the official site policy is that don't ask new question on the comments, ask a separate question because other users can't find the question and answer by search in the comment